# Why does a detached, unref'ed node.js child process keep its parent's socket open?

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process, fs

- This question is about underlying O/S handling of node.js and affects Mac and Linux.
- It deals with node.js 0.10.39, but the doc is unchanged from 4.0.0 (presumably applies there too)

The node.js manual says:

> If the detached option is set, the child process will be made the leader 
>   of a new process group. This makes it possible for the child to continue 
>   running after the parent exits.
>
> By default, the parent will wait for the detached child to exit. To 
>   prevent the parent from waiting for a given child, use the child.unref() 
>   method, and the parent's event loop will not include the child in its reference count.

When you start a node.js child process as detached and unref'ed, with separate stdio as follows:

```
var child = spawn('prg', [], { // child spawn options
  detached: true,
  stdio: [
    'ignore', // stdin
    fs.openSync( updateOutputFile, "w" ), 
    fs.openSync( updateErrorFile, "w" ) 
  ]
}
child.unref();
```

And then kill the parent, `lsof` shows that the TCP/IP (networking) sockets the parent was LISTEN-ing to are still opened and listening.  They are closed immediately the child is killed.

Why could that be?

Comment: Do you mean actual network sockets that are elsewhere or are you referring to the `updateOutputFile` and `updateErrorFile` fds?

Comment: Nothing to do with watching file handles, I mean, TCP/IP sockets are still open, you can see that with ``lsof`` or ``netstat -lnt``.  Have amended the wording to make this clear.